# How to left-center two elements using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

This is what I want to have:
[image: qwer]

I want to be able to left-center two elemenets using flexbox. It would be easy to do this (as I have shown in the jsfiddle, if I had a third box called C, but I have not found a solution to the image above this with flexbox. Anyone?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
   display: flex;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

The code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3DD6E/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style to all of the child containers:

```
.parent div{
    flex:1;
}
```

The [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) style alters the space within the flex box (available to it) that the element will take up (1=100%) or 'take up 100% of what you can' -- which in this case would be 50% of the parent.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/3DD6E/1/)